# FTP Special Characters MF vs Java

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, mainframe, codepages

We are doing a legacy modernization program VSAM/Mainframe to JAVA.
One of the modules of the legacy system generates a file and the file is FTPed by st to Microsoft windows server. The file contains special symbols ]¬|![¢^  which on FTP get translated to Ù^|!›µ.

However when we do the same functionality in Java via Apache Commons FTP Client the special characters are retained as it is ]¬|![¢^. No translations happened. The requirement is to keep the translation as it is as the downstream module are not going to be upgraded in near future.

Anyone faced this problem on how on Java Side we can do this translation what Mainframe is able to achieve during FTP?

```
ftp = new FTPClient();
ftp.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out)));
int reply;
ftp.connect(host);
reply = ftp.getReplyCode();
if (!FTPReply.isPositiveCompletion(reply)) {
    ftp.disconnect();
    throw new Exception("Exception in connecting to FTP Server");
}
ftp.login(user, pwd);
ftp.site("SBD=(IBM-1140,ISO8859-1)") //not working ftp says not recognised
```

The moment it execute the site code(networkpage, characterpage) it says not recognized.The sbd is the zos site command, anyone knows the corresponding java ftp client.

Comment: What is this JBFTP? I can't find any references to it in the IBM Knowledgecentre.

Comment: @BillWoodger apology for my limited knowledge in VSAM actually its a step EXEC = FTP

Comment: Speaking as an old IBM mainframe guy, the problem here is the translation from EBCDIC to ASCII.  Java uses Unicode, which is a superset of both and thus has a better mapping than the old system.  You will need to explicitly do the translation yourself.  However, since you posted no code we cannot really help you.

Comment: @JimGarrison updated the code in java the last line of code is where I am facing the issue I believe.

Comment: "Because there are at least 4 different EBCDIC encodings, we have opted not to provide direct support for EBCDIC. To transfer EBCDIC and other unsupported file types you must create your own filter InputStreams and OutputStreams and wrap them around the streams returned or required by the FTPClient methods." If that is still true...

Comment: Where did you find documentation of SBD= for SITE?

Comment: Out of interest, what is the particular reason for not using the ftp on the Mainframe?

Comment: @BillWoodger we are moving the system from Mainframe to JAVA. Part of modernization project. So there cannot be any dependency on Mainframe.

Comment: Have you looked into using iconv to convert the file's codepage on the mainframe and then transferring it in binary mode?

Comment: If the Mainframe isn't going to be there, how will you then ftp from it? If it is going to be there, you have a dependency on it - which involves "when is the file available?". Instead of "the file is available, let's run that job that sticks it out onto the small server", you will have to do something else, as well as getting the transfer working. As an aside, do you know Java runs on the Mainframe? No, probably you don't.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. So, instead using ftp.site i used

```
ftp.sendCommand("site sbdataconn=AAAA.BBBB.CCC");
```

AAAA.BBBB.CCC is the mainframe dataset with FB, Lrecl 256 containing the translation reference.

Change the ftp statement to

```
ftp.sendCommand("site sbdataconn=(IBM-1140,ISO8859-1)");
```

Comment: Great that it worked for you. But on your instruction I gave ftp.sendCommand("site sbdataconn=(IBM-1140,ISO8859-1)"); but still it provides 500 'SITE': command not understood . So In my case it's not working.

Comment: Try using "ftp.site("filetype=seq");" before sending sbdataconn instruction.